# Embed Runnable Python in Web Page Using Brython

Tags: python, brython

Inspecting the source of this page: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/ I noticed that it uses Brython (https://brython.info/).

I want to be able to embed runnable Python scripts in web pages for educational purposes. However the Brython website doesn't seem to explain how to do this. There are some great examples of brython running in a browser, but not as editable, pre-loaded code that users can edit and run.

Can anyone please explain how to achieve what I'm trying to do, or point me to some relevant info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the site you refer to, as well as the [brython site itself](https://brython.info/tests/editor.htm) use [ACE editor](https://ace.c9.io/) for that purpose. Check the source code.
On the brython site there is also info how [you can embed console instead](https://brython.info/tests/console.html)

**EDIT (23 March 2020):**

An alternative is [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) by Microsoft. It is used by Repl.it and is used in VSCode.

There is also [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/)

Comment: Thanks. The embed console option looks good, but it doesn't look like you can pre-load it with snippets.

Comment: That's why the primary answer to your question is the ACE editor as used by both sites. The embedded console is just yet another option.

Comment: Although this is helpful info, I can't begin to fathom how to put runnable Python snippets on a webpage using ACE and Brython. Searching for Brython + ACE yields no results. The snakify site has `<div class="visualizer_code">` containing the relevant html, but how would find out how to generate that html and make it work?